# Kibana - uptime monitor based on recent log entries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm looking to visualize the following in one my my dashboards.

The healthcheck of one of my services would be based on the amount of log entries in the past few seconds; i.e. if there were more than 5 new log entries (in an existing index) in the past 5 seconds, the dashboard's lens shows "TRUE" else shows "FALSE".

This seems possible for alerting however not for visualization.

Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

thanks in advance.